# Using Oracle 9i converting a single text column list into a 2 column list

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a list of countries

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES

COUNTRY
--------------
Austria
Belarus
Belgium
Finland
France
Iceland
Ireland
Switzerland
```

How would I select this as 2 columns e.g

```
COLUMN1          COLUMN2
-------          -------
Austria          Belarus
Belgium          Finland
France           Iceland
Ireland          Switzerland
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why its stupid Question???? That could serve his requirement

Comment: This is needed to feed a service that requires a 2 column layout and the data is not countries, it is only to act as a way to simply describe the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select country, next_country
from 
  (select country, 
         lead(country) over (order by country) next_country,
         row_number() over (order by country) rnk
   from countries
  ) 
where mod(rnk,2)=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  max(case mod(rownum - 1, 2) when 0 then country end) column1,
  max(case mod(rownum - 1, 2) when 1 then country end) column2
from countries
group by floor((rownum - 1) / 2)
order by floor((rownum - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: I like this for not using analytic functions :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can accomplish this using [Subquery Factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066378)

**Sample Query**

```
WITH 
   countrycolumn1 AS (
      SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES where COUNTRY='some condition'),
   countrycolumn2 AS (
      SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES COUNTRY='some condition' )
   SELECT col1.country as COLUMN1  , col2.country as COLUMN2 
  FROM countrycolumn1 col1,countrycolumn2 col2
   WHERE col1.countrytype == col2 .countrytype
```